# How can a spaceship get into the correct wormhole?

Tags: technology, space-travel, wormholes

There is a binary wormhole system within light years from our Solar System, the identical wormholes are orbiting each other once every 500 days. Each wormhole lead to an unique fixed address, without going through trial and error is there anyway to tell the exits before entering any of the wormholes? Assume these natural wormholes are stable and safe and our tech level is equivalent to a type 2 civilization on the Kardashev scale.

Comment: If they are identical, of course there is none, except trial and error and then carefully preserving the result for future use. Question as written can't have an answer.

Comment: Are you asking if you could know the exit before *anyone* went through the wormholes, or just how would a specific spaceship know which one was which after lots of people had already been through?

Comment: @Michael: the latter and I'm thinking of  man-made orbiting signage around the wormholes.

Answer (score 3):

Take two spaceships. Send one spaceship through one wormhole each. When they return your K2 civilization will now know where each wormhole goes, and its location.

Alternatively, your K2 civilization sets up a communications station near the wormhole binary and sends radio, laser, and if they have them FTL signals through, asking anyone on the other side to respond. There is a good chance, if you get an answer, this will give a good idea where the wormholes lead.

If you have FTL communications, build a pair of FTL signal beacons and send them through and wait until the beacon signals are detected. This will tell where the exit mouths of the wormholes are located.

Thirdly, if wormholes are more like transparent windows showing what is at the location of its exit mouth. If so, your K2 civilization sets up an observatory and makes observations about what is on the opposite side. Eventually, possibly sooner, they will build up a picture about where and what is at the exit location. Using astronomical data will be possible to know where each of wormholes emerges back into the spacetime manifold.

Answer (score 3):

## Deploy Gatekeepers

If the wormholes are absolutely identical (if not, there's no point asking this question), then you deploy beacons to orbit/follow each wormhole.

Passing ships then use the beacons to guide their way to the correct wormholes.

The beacons could also be gatekeeper ships/space stations if you want to monitor/police this end of the wormholes.